# What does this formula do?

Tags: ratio

I'm examining voltage drop across 2 series resistors. As part of my results table I am asked to calculate $\frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2} \times V_3$ and $\frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2} \times V_3$. This all relates to Kirchhoff's Voltage Law.

Is this basically finding out the ratios of one to another?

Answer (score 2):

It is calculating the voltage drop across each resistor of a series pair.  You connected $R_1$ and $R_2$ in series and placed the combination across $V_3$.  But you should **really** understand what the circuit is before trying to apply a formula you don't understand.  This should also go on electrical engineering instead of math.

Answer (score 1):

Those are the formulas for finding the voltage drop across $R_1$ and $R_2$. The wiki page for [Voltage Dividers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider) should be of some help.